# How to write custom spaceship operator in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

I don't understand why this code doesn't compile. According to some websites, `a == b` should be rewritten as `a.operator<=>(b) == 0`, however both clang and gcc fail to compile.

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
public:
    int x_ = 0;

public:
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A& o) const 
    {
        return int(x_ == o.x_ ? 0 : x_ < o.x_ ? -1 : 1) <=> 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
  A a{1};
  A b{2};

  if(a == b) printf("a==b\n");
}
```

However, if you use the default, everything works!

```cpp
...
   std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const A& o) const = default;
...
```

So my question is, how do you write the `default` implementation of `<=>` by hand?

Comment: First, the hand-written one should be just `return x_ <=> o.x_;` Second, if you write a custom `<=>`, you have to also write a custom `==`. A defaulted `<=>` also generates a defaulted `==`.

Comment: " According to some websites [...]" Those websites are incorrect. `a == b` does not rewrite to `(a <=> b) == 0`.

Comment: *"According to some websites..."*  Those website were using the early draft of the C++20 spaceship operator proposal.  The C++20 standard separated out the `==` behavior, because a custom `<=>` could be inefficient for `==` and `!=` predicates.